# Why my div floated in the right side, doesn't start from top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this floating elements but the right element it start some pixels down then the left. Any idea how to fix this?

here is my code that I am using for this and please have a look on JSFiddle to see how it works https://jsfiddle.net/eoopvgmc/1/

CSS:

```
container{
        width: 1472px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .main_content {
        background: blue;
        float: left;
        height: 1500px;
        width: 500px;
    }
    .top_banner{
        background: orange;
        float: left;
        height: 250px;
        width: 500px;
    }
    .left-zone {
        background: yellow;
        float: left;
        top: 0px;
        width: 224px;
        height: 284px;
    }
    .right-zone {
        background: red;
        float: left;
        top: 0px;
        width: 224px;
        height: 284px;
    }
```

JS:

```
(function($) {
        var element = $('.left-zone'),
            originalY = element.offset().top;
        var topMargin = 0;
        element.css('position', 'relative');
        $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            element.stop(false, false).animate({
                top: scrollTop < originalY ? 0 : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);

    (function($) {
        var element = $('.right-zone'),
            originalY = element.offset().top;
        var topMargin = 0;
        element.css('position', 'relative');
        $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            element.stop(false, false).animate({
                top: scrollTop < originalY ? 0 : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: It seems I misunderstood what you mean due to jsfiddle's window size, sry.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am just worried why it doesn't start from top

Comment: Yep, I got to get a bigger view or I can get what i looks like, if I find a solution, I'll undelete my answer.

Comment: Your `container` in the CSS is missing the dot `.container`

Comment: I've updated bot it starts to scroll when it reach 250px

Comment: Now is fully working

Comment: So you question is solved now?

Comment: yes, thanks for your help. Was just the top: -250px; and bit of work on JS for the right div

Comment: Take a look what it looks like on my [test page](https://i.imgur.com/zaDJmSb.png), I think I still don't get the point, sry :/

Comment: have a look on my JSFiddle and you will understand